# XSLTForms using position() to select repeat element from another instance

Tags: xpath, xforms, xsltforms

Background:

Building a form (using XSLTForms) that is submitted, then the user may resubmit at a later date. We want the user to see the values of their previous submission next to the form input, so we're loading 2 instances 'data-set' and 'old-data-set'. This is working in most instances, but not where we have repeats. for whatever reason the position() method always returns '1' when calling data from the 'old-data-set' instance. For example:

```
<xf:repeat nodeset="instance('data-set')/references/reference">
  <xf:group ref=".">
    <xf:label>Reference <xf:output value="position()"/></xf:label>
    <xf:input ref="/org_name">...</xf:input>
    <xf:output ref="instance('old-data-set')/references/reference[position()]/org_name"/>
  </xf:group>
</xf:repeat>
```

The `position()` method works in the label, but always returns '1' when attempting to get the value from the second instance. For example the above produces:

```
<label>Reference 1</label>
<input>Org name 1</input>
<output>Old org name 1</output>

<label>Reference 2</label>
<input>Org name 2</input>
<output>Old org name 1</output>

<label>Reference 3</label>
<input>Org name 3</input>
<output>Old org name 1</output>
```

How can I call the position() of the repeat so I can use it to get the correct value from the 'old-data-set' instance?

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that inside the predicate (inside the `[]`, the context is different and `position()` refers to the position of the old-data-set `reference` node rather than the current `reference` node in your iteration.

I'm not familiar with XSLTForms, but how's this?

```
<xf:repeat nodeset="instance('data-set')/references/reference">
  <xf:group ref=".">
    <xf:label>Reference <xf:output value="position()"/></xf:label>
    <xf:input ref="/org_name">...</xf:input>
    <xf:output 
      ref="instance('old-data-set')/references/reference[count(current()/preceding-sibling::reference) + 1]/org_name"/>
  </xf:group>
</xf:repeat>
```

Comment: I thought it would something along those lines. I suspect this isn't supported by xsltforms, it's throwing an initialisation error.

Comment: This should be supported by XSLTForms so I would like to have a full test case to check this.